# Problemas con bicola en java, quiero insertar de ambos lados datos en una cola, pero correctamente no me funciona

Tags: java

Este es el problema que estoy haciendo una bicola para insertar datos en ambos a lados de la cola, pero cuando inserto datos a la izquierda no me funciona, en cambio al meter datos de lado derecho si funciona.

```
public class NodoCola {
    public int dato;
    public NodoCola siguiente;

    public int getDato() {
        return dato;
    }

    public void setDato(int dato) {
        this.dato = dato;
    }

    public NodoCola getSiguiente() {
        return siguiente;
    }

    public void setSiguiente(NodoCola siguiente) {
        this.siguiente = siguiente;
    }

    public NodoCola(int dato){
        this.dato=dato;
        this.siguiente= null;

    }


// --------------------------Clase Cola--------------------------
public class Cola {

    NodoCola inicio, fin;
    int tama;

    public Cola() {
        inicio = fin = null;
        tama = 0;
    }

    public boolean colaVacia() {
        return inicio == null;
    }
    public void insertarDatoDerecha(int elem){
        NodoCola nuevo= new NodoCola(elem);
        if (colaVacia()) {
            nuevo.setDato(elem);
            inicio = nuevo;
        } else {
            nuevo.setDato(elem);
            fin.siguiente = nuevo;
        }
        fin = nuevo;
        tama++;
    }

    public void insertarDatoIzquierda(int elem) {
        NodoCola nuevo = new NodoCola(elem);
        if (colaVacia()) {
            nuevo.setDato(elem);
            fin= nuevo;

        } else{
            nuevo.setDato(elem);
            fin=nuevo.siguiente;
    }
        inicio=nuevo;
        tama++;
    }
```

Comment: Y cuando investigastes el problema, ¿qué encontrastes?

Answer (score 1):

Antes que nada tienes un concepto equivocado de cola o bicola (basándome en lo que implementaste), una bicola es una colección de objetos uno detrás de otro en el cual puedes insertar o eliminar el primero o el ultimo de sus datos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora con respecto a lo que implementaste lo que tu tienes es un árbol ya que tienes tu objeto ***NodoCola Siguiente*** dentro de tu objeto ***NodoCola***
entonces en ves de tener un elemento detrás de otro tienes un elemento dentro de otro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez aclarado esto omitiré el hecho de que estamos llamando a un árbol como cola y te ayudare a resolver el problema de tu código que es la principal razón por la que se abrió la pregunta.

Primero debes saber que si pasas parámetros por medio del constructor

```
NodoCola nuevo= new NodoCola(elem);
```

No necesitas volver a pasar el mismo parámetro por medio del método set

```
nuevo.setDato(elem);
```

Segundo en tu clase cola tienes definidas 2 NodoCola

```
NodoCola inicio, fin;
```

Debes de tener en cuenta que estas trabajando solo con una estructura y no con dos sin importar que esta estructura tenga un elemento de inicio y un elemento de fin (mejor dicho un elemento que contiene a todos y un elemento que es contenido en todos) Por lo que solo se tiene que trabajar con un objeto NodoCola

Tercero jamas manejes variables globales es tus clases de lógica (business), es considerado una mala practica, por que tu código no es escalable y es difícil de desacoplar. Como ejemplo, imagina que mas adelante el usuario quiera insertar en 2 colas distintas pero intercalando las inserciones entre amabas como tu variable de cola es global y en ella se guardan tus inserciones deberás de hacer mas modificaciones para que ese código pueda funcionar, cuando el usuario maneja 2 o mas colas. Por ello te aconsejo recibir como parámetro la cola con la que trabajara y retornarla, si hace esto cuando el usuario quiera manejar 2 o mas colas lo único que envías es la cola en la que quiere insertar sin tener que modificar la lógica de negocios.

```
public class Cola {

 public static void main (String[] args) {
   NodoCola cola = new NodoCola();
   Cola obj = new Cola();

   cola = obj.insertarDatoInterior(cola,3);
   cola = obj.insertarDatoInterior(cola,4);
   cola = obj.insertarDatoExterior(cola,2);
   cola = obj.insertarDatoInterior(cola,5);
   cola = obj.insertarDatoExterior(cola,1);
   cola = obj.insertarDatoInterior(cola,6);
   cola = obj.insertarDatoExterior(cola,0);
   obj.imprimeCola(cola);

 }
 public NodoCola insertarDatoInterior(NodoCola cola, int elem) {
   NodoCola elementoCola = cola;

   //Si su dato es null significa que la cola es nueva
   if(elementoCola.getDato() == null) {
     elementoCola.setDato(elem);
   }

   //La cola ya existe
   else { 
     //Busca el ultimo elemento anidado
     while (elementoCola.getSiguiente() != null){
       elementoCola = elementoCola.getSiguiente();
     } 
     //Crea nuevo elemento que se guardara en el utimo elemento anidado
     NodoCola nuevoElemento = new NodoCola();
     nuevoElemento.setDato(elem);

     //Guarda el nuevoElemento en el ultimo elemento anidado
     elementoCola.setSiguiente(nuevoElemento);
   }

   return cola;
 }

 public NodoCola insertarDatoExterior(NodoCola cola, int elem) {

   //Si su dato es null significa que la cola es nueva
   if(cola.getDato() == null) {
     cola.setDato(elem);
     return cola;
   }

   //Si ya existe
   else {
     //Crea el nuevo elemento que contendra la cola ya existente
     NodoCola nuevoElemento = new NodoCola();
     nuevoElemento.setDato(elem);

     //Se anida la cola existente dentro del nuevo elemento
     nuevoElemento.setSiguiente(cola);
     return nuevoElemento;
   }

 }
 public void imprimeCola(NodoCola cola) {
   int i=0;
   NodoCola elemento = cola;
   while(elemento.getDato() != null){
     System.out.println("Elemento "+ i +" es "+elemento.getDato());
     if(elemento.getSiguiente() != null) {
       elemento = elemento.getSiguiente();
     }
     else {
       break;
     }
     i++;
   }
 }
}
```

**Nota**: aunque incluí el main dentro de la misma clase solo fue por flojera, tu no metas el main ahí, en tu clase NodoCola cambie el tipo de dato ***dato*** a Integer ya que con el puedes manejar el dato como null antes de que el usuario agregue algo.